# Zend Framework Modules Issues

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am running Zend Framework 1.11.10 on Ubuntu 11.10. I have created 3 modules named "admin", "music", "movies". But when I visit "/admin", "/music" or "/movies", I get a 404 error.

I have tried different combinations of autoloaders in both application.ini and bootstrap but none worked. So, I have created yet another fresh project. Created the modules, turned on error reporting and here is the source code: https://bitbucket.org/masnun/zf-modules/src

I really can't find what's going wrong. I want "/admin" to load the admin module (admin/index/index").

Any helps?

Regards,
Masnun

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and a vhost and/or .htaccess configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project in the repository is not configured for use with modules. The easiest way to get things going, is to put `app/controllers` and `app/views` in a module `default` and then switch the following in your application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
-->
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

After that the URLs /{module}/{controller}/{action} should work, if no module is specified, default will be used.

For ZF to recognize resources from modules, you should place a bootstrap.php in each module's folder containing the following:

```
class {MODULE}_Bootstrap extends Zend_Applocation_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

and add `resources.modules[] = ""` to your application.ini